# Aho-Corasick string matching in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, strings, haskell

I implemented Aho-Corasick string matching in Haskell. It is a purely functional implementation compared to many other implementations.

The input to build an automata is `[([a],b)]`. which is a list of `(pattern,output)` pairs. 
`b` has to form a monoid, so we know what to do when more than one match occurs at the same place.

I borrowed many idea from the [KMP implementation by Twan van Laarhoven](http://twanvl.nl/blog/haskell/Knuth-Morris-Pratt-in-Haskell)(which I suspect is a implementation of the MP instead of KMP algorithm).

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Function
import Control.Arrow
data Automaton a b = Node {delta  :: a -> Automaton a b,
                           output :: b
                         }
-- assume the input function eq is a equivalence relation, then this
-- produce all the equivalent classes.
equivalentClasses :: (a->a->Bool)->[a]->[[a]]
equivalentClasses eq = foldl parts []
  where parts [] a = [[a]]
        parts (x:xs) a 
         | eq (head x) a = (a:x):xs
         | otherwise     = x:parts xs a

buildAutomaton :: (Monoid b,Eq a) => [([a],b)] -> Automaton a b
buildAutomaton xs = automaton
  where automaton = build (const automaton) xs mempty

-- this builds one node of the automaton. Tying the knot happens everywhere
build :: (Monoid b,Eq a)=> (a -> Automaton a b) -> [([a],b)] -> b -> Automaton a b
build trans' xs out = node
  where node  = Node trans out
        trans a
          | isNothing next = trans' a
          | otherwise      = fromJust next
          where next = lookup a table
        table =  map transPair $ equivalentClasses (on (==) (head . fst)) xs
        transPair xs = (a, build (delta (trans' a)) ys out)
         where a  = head $ fst $ head xs
               (ys,zs) = partition (not . null . fst) $ map (first tail) xs
               out = mappend (mconcat $ map snd zs) (output $ trans' a)

-- this function simulates the automaton.
match :: Eq a => Automaton a b -> [a] -> [b]
match a xs = map output $ scanl delta a xs

-- an example to check if a list is a sublist of another list
isInfixOf' :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
isInfixOf' xs ys = getAll $ mconcat $ match (buildAutomaton [(xs, All True)]) ys
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be nice if the code was ordered for exposed functions versus internal helpers. It looks like `buildAutomaton` is the exposed API along with the `Automaton` data type. However, `buildAutomaton` is the one function missing any comments or docs.

`trans` looks a lot like `maybe` from the Prelude/Data.Maybe.

Use explicit imports to make clear where your functions are coming from.